AppSync Stack Identity Pool definition
I am trying to connect an already existing IdentityPool to my AppSync API Configuration.
When instantianting a new IdentityPool i can access the properties .authenticatedUserRole and .unauthenticatedUserRole. But when i use the methods .fromIdentityPoolArn or .fromIdentityPoolId to fetch the existing IdentityPool i can't access the properties. Why?!
const idPool = IdentityPool.fromIdentityPoolArn(this, 'importedIdentityPool', 'arn...');

i need this for the identityPoolConfig:
identityPoolConfig: {
      identityPoolId: takes a String,
      authenticatedUserRole: takes IRole,
      unauthenticatedUserRole: takes IRole
    }


Try this
import {Role } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';

const authrole = Role.fromRoleArn(this, 'id', 'arn');
const unauthrole = Role.fromRoleArn(this, 'id', 'arn');

identityPoolConfig: {
     identityPoolId: 'id',
     authenticatedUserRole: authrole,
     unauthenticatedUserRole: unauthrole
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
